# Could not resolve parameter [0] in exception error

Tags: java, spring, exception, controller

I want to throw exception in service layer:

```
    List<String> cellValuesOfTheRow = getColumnValuesForRow(row, false);
    logger.info("currentRowNumber: {}, cellValuesOfTheRow: {}", currentRowNumber, cellValuesOfTheRow);

    if (cellValuesOfTheRow.contains(null)) {
        throw new NullFieldValueException(currentRowNumber);
    }
```

if that **list** contains null value, i want it to throw exception.

I made a custom exception:

```
public class NullFieldValueException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8460356990632230194L;

    int currentRowNumber;

    public NullFieldValueException(int currentRowNumber) {
        super();
        this.currentRowNumber = currentRowNumber;
    }

}
```

Also i have controller advice:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GenericExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @ExceptionHandler(NullFieldValueException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handle(int currentRowNumber, Locale locale) {

        String errorMessage =
                messageSource.getMessage(
                "error.null.field.value" , new Object[]{currentRowNumber},locale);

        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
        error.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE.value());
        error.setMessage(errorMessage);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
}
```

This is from **messages/messages_en.properties**:

```
#nullpointer
error.null.field.value=Empty or null value for the row number: {0}
```

This is **messageconfig**:

```
@Configuration
public class MessageConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource
                = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);

        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());

        return bean;
    }
}
```

But it gives error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.example.demo.response.ErrorResponse> com.example.demo.config.GenericExceptionHandler.handle(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale): No suitable resolver
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:164) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:407) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:61) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:141) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1300) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1111) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at
```

So is it wrong to use together **controlleradvice** and custom exception?

Answer (score 7):

Your ExceptionHandler expects the thrown Exception as the first argument, instead of the `int` currentRowNumber:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(NullFieldValueException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handle(NullFieldValueException e, Locale locale) {
   int rowNumber = e.getCurrentRowNumber();
   ...
}
```

And add a getter `getCurrentRowNumber()` in your exception class to retrieve the row number.